# turtlebot navigation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

can i build my map without doing calibration because i have only irobot create ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53912/turtlebot-navigation/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-01-31**:
what kind of calibration are you talking about??

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
this one
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-01**:
I have a turtlebot which has a create base. I did not do any calibration for my bot as mentioned in the link..

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
Can you tell me how to built your map without using calibration ? as my irobot create dosen't contain this part http://store.iheartengineering.com/ihe-0200-0000-fa00.html

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-01**:
@shade:- you bought the full turtle bot with (power/sensor gyro board )..or only icreate robot ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-01**:
Since u dont have the gyroscope sensor, wat exact set of readings are you missing??

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
How can i do it without having gyro sensor?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-14**:
what is turtlebot calibration ?! and why need this ?!
see this my help !
http://answers.ros.org/question/10868/calibrating-turtlebot-odometry-without-gyroimu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Considering the comments I guess by "without calibration" you mean to say that you don't have an IMU?

In that case, try [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping). It doesn't require odometry and might work for you.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-01**:
@dornhege :  Does that technique works without "board/sensor gyro board".. can perform mapping task with the normal icreate robot base ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-01**:
Yes, it doesn't require odometry in principle. Just a laser or similar. How good it works only with a kinect and thus very limited data is another question.

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-01**:
that's sounds great...i will start work on this technique ... and hope it leads to a good results ...i love this community ^*^...thank you very much,sir. and thanks to the question asker ^*^

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Wafaay I am not sure of the turtlebot specification that I have in my lab. @marwa if ur using gmapping algorithm then all you need is laser scan and position of laser sensor w.r.t to world. Laser position is defined with respect to base_link of robot which in defined in odometry frame. So if u have laser readings and sensor position then mapping can easily be done.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
Thank u ... is there any tutorial explains how i can use this method ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-01**:
look for gmapping tutorial,that should help....